# Googlebot-Image/1.0 requesting multiple images

Tags: apache, http, googlebot

for a while I experienced that the google image bot is requesting a bunch of images in a single request. This request always ends up in a 404, but all images exist.

The request url consists a comma seperated list of URLs.

Here is a line from the apache access.log:

```
66.249.76.96 - - [21/Nov/2018:15:25:14 +0100] "GET /images/img1.jpg,https://example.com/images/img2.jpg,https://example.com/images/img3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 10459 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
```

Is this request type even possible? And how can I fix the server to serve the images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found the cause? I am experiencing a similar issue